# Deducing that a group $G$ has order $2^{n}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> **Problem:** Suppose that $G$ is a finite Abelian group with $x^{2} = e$ for every $x \in G$, given that for any subgroup $H$ of $G$, $H \cup Hg$ is a subgroup of $G$ with order $2|H|$. Deduce that $G$ has order $2^{n}$ for some non-negative integer $n$ and that for each $m = 0,1,\dots,n$ it contains a subgroup of order $2^{m}$.

The latter result seems to lend itself to an inductive proof on $m$. But I cannot seem to get the initial deduction that the cardinality of $G$ must be of the form $2^{n}$. Why must this be the case?

Comment: Start with an element $x\neq e$. You have $x^2=e$ so $ H =\langle x\rangle$ is of order $2$. If $H=G$ conclude. Else, take $g\in G-H$ and then $H\cup Hg$ is by hypothesis of order $2|H|$. Repeat the argument for $H\cup Hg$ which is now a subgroup just as $H$ previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what the meaning of all the assumptions is. Firstly, the conclusion holds for *any* finite group, not just abelian (by Cauchy's theorem that if $p$ divides $|G|$ than there is an element of order $p.$ If you don't know Cauchy's theorem (which is not hard), take your element $x,$ consider $G/\langle x \rangle,$ that still has the property that every element has order $2,$ so induction works.